# Residual standard error in GLS models

Tags: r, regression, heteroscedasticity, generalized-least-squares

I am conducting a "residual analysis" in R (essentially an adapted [Event Study](http://lipas.uwasa.fi/%7Esjp/articles/sp_acta_wasaensia_143_327-354.pdf)), where I aim to use the RSE to construct a residual confidence interval to identify "outlier" observations.

However, I am faced with a situation where I have heteroscedasticity in my data, so intuitively I expect these residual CIs to vary with $X$. To adjust for this I am using a GLS model, which allows me to estimate the parameter $\Omega$ with which $\sigma_i$ varies. To that end, I am having some trouble understanding and interpreting the output of R's `nlme::gls()` function such that I can calculate this.

Here is a sample code illustrating the problem:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lmtest)
library(nlme)

#Gen data
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(1000)
x <- sort(x)+5

y <- 1.5 + 3*x
dat <- data.frame(cbind(x, y))
quantile(dat$y)

#Introduce artificial heteroscedasticity such that residual variance decreases as x increases
dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(y = jitter(y, factor = (max(x)-x)*1000))
plot(dat$x, dat$y)

#OLS and check for heteroscedasticity
ols <- lm(y ~ x, data = dat)
summary(ols)
bptest(ols)

#GLS 
gls <- gls(y ~ x, data = dat, weights = varPower())
summary(gls)
```

In a normal OLS situation, I can just use the `summary(ols)$sigma` call to get the RSE and easily construct a single residual CI that applies to all residuals. In this case, I cannot do so because the CIs will ostensibly tighten as $x$ increases. My question is twofold:

(1) How can I get/calculate $\sigma_i$ from this output?

(2) You'll note that the mean of the residuals is no longer approximately zero (compare `mean(summary(ols)$residuals` with `mean(summary(gls)$residuals`), nor does it seem to be normally distributed (`qqnorm(gls)`). Is anyone able to provide insight on why this is happening? Am I using GLS inappropriately here?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, if anyone comes across this question in the future, I have figured out the solution to this issue. If you check the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/residuals.gls.html) for the GLS `nlme::residuals()` function, you can see the following:

1. Calling `residuals(gls, type = "response")` gives you traditional "raw" residuals.
2. Calling `residuals(gls, type = "pearson")` gives standardized residuals, which are simply the raw residuals scaled by their standard errors.

Subsequently, the following code will give you observation-level residual standard errors:

```
resids_raw <- residuals(gls, type = "response")
resids_scaled <- residuals(gls, type = "pearson")
se_i <- as.numeric(resids_raw /resids_scaled)
```

As a sanity check, you can see that the se_i vector decreases with x, which is what we would expect/hope. The `mean(se_i)` is also roughly comparable to the OLS RSE (`summary(ols)$sigma`). Hope this helps.